# Issue with tracking a cursor in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Can anyone help me clear up this question?  I'm not sure what my instructor means...

4. Write a statement that fetches all records after the cursor in #3 has executed. A message should be displayed to indicate that a course has been deleted.

Here's #3 and my solution:

3. Write a cursor for deleting all courses with enrollments of less than 20 students. Display course reference numbers and enrollments after courses are deleted.

My Code:

```
DECLARE @enrollment INT
DECLARE killCourse_Cursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT Enrollment FROM Course

OPEN killCourse_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM killCourse_Cursor INTO @enrollment
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    IF(@enrollment < 20)
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM Course WHERE @enrollment = Enrollment
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM killCourse_Cursor INTO @enrollment
END

CLOSE killCourse_Cursor
DEALLOCATE killCourse_Cursor

SELECT Ref_Number, Enrollment FROM Course
```

The table only has 10 rows and after I'm done 5 remain. I guess I'm misunderstanding the question?  Once I update a table and delete rows... is there a way to know what's been deleted?  Very confused here...

Comment: Why don't you ask your instructor for clarification on the question?

Comment: Thanks for admitting it is homework.  In the real work, I cannot imagine using a cursor for this (or almost anything).

Comment: Your instructor is teaching you to use cursors?  Make sure you forget how to use them immediately after you're done with that class.  To say that they are normally bad practice is an understatement.

Comment: You don't mention the schema.  Is there by chance a "deleted" field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first solution starts out weak.  Even if forced to use a cursor, you should **NOT** select records you don't need.  Have the `WHERE` clause do the work for you.

You should also use the course Ref_Number to delete the course, not the enrollment!

Your cursor could build a temporary table with information about the deleted courses for later use -- but my example shows that you might as well skip the cursor.

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Course ( Ref_Number INT PRIMARY KEY
                    , Enrollment INT
                    , Title VARCHAR(99))
```

and some sample data

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Course VALUES(100,22,'Java') 
INSERT INTO dbo.Course VALUES(101,2,'Objective C')
INSERT INTO dbo.Course VALUES(102,3,'Into to Apple Development')
INSERT INTO dbo.Course VALUES(200,32,'Databases are cool')
INSERT INTO dbo.Course VALUES(201,22,'Primary Keys and You')
INSERT INTO dbo.Course VALUES(202,2,'Advanced Apple Development')
```

you can gather and remember the ones to be deleted

```
SELECT Ref_Number, Enrollment, Title 
   INTO #KillList 
   FROM dbo.Course 
WHERE Enrollment < 20
```

then delete them all at once

```
DELETE FROM kc 
   FROM dbo.Course kc JOIN #KillList kl ON kl.Ref_Number = kc.Ref_Number
```

and print the list of those that remain

```
SELECT Ref_Number, Enrollment FROM dbo.Course
```

or print the entire list, including those that were deleted

```
SELECT Ref_Number, Enrollment, Title, '' as status FROM dbo.Course 
UNION ALL SELECT Ref_Number, Enrollment , Title, 'DELETED!' as status 
    FROM #KillList kl 
ORDER BY 1
```

Here is the same thing using a dreaded `cursor`

```
SELECT * INTO #KillList2 FROM dbo.Course WHERE Enrollment < 20

DECLARE @RefNum INT
DECLARE killCourse_Cursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT Ref_Number FROM Course WHERE Enrollment < 20

OPEN killCourse_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM killCourse_Cursor INTO @RefNum
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM Course WHERE Ref_Number = @RefNum  
   FETCH NEXT FROM killCourse_Cursor INTO @RefNum  
END

CLOSE killCourse_Cursor
DEALLOCATE killCourse_Cursor

SELECT Ref_Number, Enrollment FROM Course
SELECT Ref_Number, Enrollment, Title, '' as status FROM dbo.Course 
UNION ALL SELECT Ref_Number, Enrollment , Title, 'DELETED!' as status 
   FROM #KillList2 kl 
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with forgetting cursors when you are done. A couple of things come to mind.  Have you been learning about triggers too?  With a trigger, you could tell if a record was deleted and maybe write it to a separate table or something.

If the part that reads "A message should be displayed to indicate that a course has been deleted" is a second task, and not a part of the first sentence, maybe it simply means to use a PRINT statement to write to the "Messages" tab when a record was deleted.

I don't of anything within the cursor process that maintains a list of record changes (deletes, update, etc).